# Installing IE7 without a working IE6

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, download, installation

I'm working with a relative's PC with Windows XP (gold edition) on it, and for some reason, their IE6 is not working at all. Is there a way to get IE7 installed on their PC without a working Internet browser?

If anyone could point me to a related SU post or website with the instructions for this, I'd appreciate it.

*Of course, I could use a flash disk to install Firefox and do it from there, but I don't have it with me, and it will cost me a few hours to get home for it.

Comment: I have a question: if you can't get access to the internet, how are you making this post?

Comment: Also, what's "Windows XP Gold Edition?"

Comment: Windows XP "Gold" is XP *before* SP1 came out. And yes, since you're curious, I was at a nearby Internet cafe at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Windows Update and when it comes up with a list of updates, just 'Check' IE 7 from the list , download and install.

Comment: Found the steps to installing Firefox through FTP here (http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/browser/installfirefoxwithoutie.html). But the system kept crashing on me. I ended up reinstalling Windows. I'm accepting this one, nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: Does it suck to get the correct answer without an upvote?

Comment: uhm windows update uses IE to display doesn't it?

Comment: yes and no, Windows updates uses IE or it can also display the updates in a local client on the machine

Answer (score 0):

windows xp gold edition is counterfeit software but internet explorer 7 is a non-genuine update if you need it directly from Microsoft, but internet explorer is easily broken and no one can repair it so go to another browser like firefox ... as windows xp gold crap is old the computer is also so chrome, flock and k-meleon are also good choices but less well supported ...

Comment: If I could install Firefox *without a working browser* I would have done so, and I wouldn't have had to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

one thing useful for you > portable softwares like portableapps liberkey framakey (no shame I like Framakey ubuntu-fr remix software best windows/mac/linux open source stuff all-in-one but in french soon being translated ...) or if still living no-install website ...

you pick firefox portable for a run there nothing better ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the setup for IE7 from anywhere and install it, without the need for using a browser. I have one setup, if you want it then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have a friend download firefox portable from his computer and use it to browser the internet and re-download IE7 (IE8 is even better, though firefox is the best).